# Issue on Click and Alert on Button in Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/tkrx9dwp/1/) and let me know why the

```
$(".onealert").on("click",function(){
    alert("You clicked on A");
});
```

is not functioning?

here is the code I have :

```
<div class="the-box">
    <div class="pull-right btn-group btn-group-sm" id="downloadSelect">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button> 
        <button href="#" class="trigger btn btn-default">2</button> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="head hide">Alphabet Select</div>
    <div class="content hide">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                <button type="button" id="1Download" class="btn btn-default onealert">A</button>
                <button type="button" id="2Download" class="btn btn-default">B</button>
                <button type="button" id="3Download" class="btn btn-default">C</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not getting any error message too!

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because Bootstrap builds new markup for the little dialog as it appears, using the hidden markup as a template only, which means it's dynamic content that didn't exist when you added the event handler, and you'll need a delegated handler

```
$('.the-box').on("click", ".onealert", function(){
    alert("You clicked on A");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tkrx9dwp/3/)